# Time series graph does not show a fluid line

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, timeserieschart

I am quite new to r and am trying to perform ARIMA time series forecast. The data I am looking into in electricity load per 15 min. My data looks as follows:

```
 day month year PTE periode_van periode_tm gemeten_uitwisseling
 1   1    01 2010   1      0 secs   900 secs                 2636
 2   1    01 2010   2    900 secs  1800 secs                 2621
 3   1    01 2010   3   1800 secs  2700 secs                 2617
 4   1    01 2010   4   2700 secs  3600 secs                 2600
 5   1    01 2010   5   3600 secs  4500 secs                 2582
 geplande_import geplande_export                date weekend
 1             719            -284 2010-01-01 00:00:00       0
 2             719            -284 2010-01-01 00:15:00       0
 3             719            -284 2010-01-01 00:30:00       0
 4             719            -284 2010-01-01 00:45:00       0
 5             650            -253 2010-01-01 01:00:00       0
 weekday Month gu_ma
 1       5    01    NA
 2       5    01    NA
 3       5    01    NA
 4       5    01    NA
 5       5    01    NA
```

to create a time series I have used the following code

```
library("zoo")
ZOO <- zoo(NLData$gemeten_uitwisseling, 
order.by=as.POSIXct(NLData$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

ZOO <- na.approx(ZOO)
tsNLData <- ts(ZOO)

plot(tsNLData)
```

I have also tried the following

```
NLDatats <- ts(NLData$gemeten_uitwisseling, frequency = 96)
```

However when I plot the data I get the following;

[image: Time Series plot]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the problem is? It looks like there are seasonal and diurnal cycles in your data. The graph appears to be correct and possibly even expected considering what you are plotting.

Comment: @Roland I am trying to do an ARIMA forecast, but it constantly get very high p values and my ACF and PACF generate high values. So I was wondering whether I did something wrong in my time-series as in other examples the graphs do not look this way. I have removed seasonality but did not remove diurnal cycles so that might solve the issue.

Comment: So, your actual problem is something you don't show ...

Comment: @Roland apologies, thought that this was the problem, but it appears its not, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any problem with your graph, but your data come in 15 minute intervals, and you are plotting 4 years worth of data. So naturally it will look like a dark shaded region because there is no way to show the thousands of data points you have in your series in a single plot.

If you are struggling to handle this much data, you can consider sampling from your data frame before plotting, although this will remove seasonality and autocorrelation from the outcome. That can be helpful if you want to know average values of your outcome over time, but not as helpful to see the seasonal and autocorrelative structure in the data.

See the code below that uses `dplyr` and `ggplot2` to plot some simulated time series that illustrates these issues. It's always best to start with simulated data and then work with your own data.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

sim_data <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=.88,order=c(1,0,0)),n=10000,sd=.3)

#Too many points
data_frame(y=as.numeric(sim_data),x=1:10000) %>% ggplot(aes(y=y,x=x)) + geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() + xlab('Time') + ylab('Y_t')


#Sample from data (random sample)
#However, this will remove autocorrelation/seasonality
data_frame(y=as.numeric(sim_data),x=1:10000) %>% sample_n(500) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=y,x=x)) + geom_line() + theme_minimal() + xlab('Time') + ylab('Y_t')


# Plot a subset, which preserves autocorrelation and seasonality
data_frame(y=as.numeric(sim_data),x=1:10000) %>% slice(1:300) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=y,x=x)) + geom_line() + theme_minimal() + xlab('Time') + ylab('Y_t')
```